# Display JSON object using JSP/ JSTL tags in UI?

Tags: json, jsp, jstl

I am getting a json response from java to jsp in the below format:

```
[
   {
      "title":"JAVA",
      "time":"2hrs"
   },
   {
      "title":"JSP"
   },
   {
      "title":"JSTL"
   },
   {
      "title":"JQUERY"
   }
]
```

This i have to iterate it and show in the JSP. I dont want to display it through javascript / jquery because my requirement demands me to display json object using jsp, jstl. Please suggest me some solution?

Comment: http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Always do it in javascript. This way you will send less html to browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse the JSON input in your controller, with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for example, and add the data to simple objects. These you should pass to your model, which is available in your view. In you view simply iterate the created objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i was sending the json response in a string format ans then was trying to iterate which was causing the issue. Thanks for the quick reply.